# How to adjust spacing between buttons css

Tags: html, css

I have the following home page. I am trying to create spacing between these buttons so they don't touch each other however margin-top/bottom is not creating the spacing. Not sure why.

[image]

**index.html**

```
<div class="large-hero">
    <img class="large-hero__image" src="./assets/images/workplace-hi-dpi.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="large-hero__btn-content">
        <a class="btn btn--home" href="./job-seeker.html">Job Seekers</a><br>
        <a class="btn btn--home" href="./employer.html">Find Talent</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_large-hero.css**

```
.large-hero {
    border-bottom: 5px solid $mainRed;
    position: relative;

    &__image {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0.85;
    }

    &__btn-content {
        background-color: yellow;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

**_btn.css**

```
.btn {
    &--home {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: rgba($mainRed, .70);
        padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
        border-radius: 37.5px;
        font-size: 1.25rem;
        margin-bottom: 5rem;

        @mixin atMedium {
            padding: 1.2rem 5rem;
            border-radius: 37.5px;
            font-size: 1.75rem;
            margin-right: 5rem;
            margin-left: 5rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the files extensions are css than you are using sass feature which can not be implemented in css..